# Can same thread be used to execute many tasks one by one without destroying and re-creating thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Can same thread be used to execute many tasks one by one without destroying and re-creating thread?

```
public class SimpleThreadPool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executorService.execute(worker); // How many threads are created?
        }

        executorService.shutdown();

        while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {

        }
        System.out.println("All threads Executed");
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't that what a threadpool is for?

Comment: That's what I want to know how it internally works?

Comment: There will be 5 threads because that's the size of the `FixedThreadPool` you asked for. Did you read the documentation for that?

Comment: Yes :-).  In your example, the ExecutorService will manage the threads that will do the work - and by using newFixedThreadPool(5), you will have exactly 5 threads doing work.  If more than 5 workers are queued up with the executor, it will re-assign threads to the next worker in the queue, as they complete work on the previous worker.

Comment: @moilejter I understand Thread as 

Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable{@override run()}); 

How th shifts from one Runnable r1 to r2, without destroying th and recreating it?

Comment: @cha0site I am not understanding how Runnable instances switches in line `Thread th = new Thread(r1)` and `th=new Thread(r2)` I assume `r1` and `r2` as two tasks and `th` as a single thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the same `Thread` can be used to run more than one task. This is what `ExecutorService` does: it maintains a thread pool for reusing threads rather than creating new ones for each task. A rough idea of how this is done is below:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class MyExecutor implements Executor {

  private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  private final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
      while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        queue.take().run();
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }, "my-executor-thread");

  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(command);
    queue.add(command);
    synchronized (thread) {
      if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
        thread.start();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

*Note that the real implementations are much more complicated than this. For instance, I did not add a way to create a new `Thread` if some error causes the current one to die. I also don't protect the `Thread` from possible exceptions thrown from the `Runnable`.*

As you can see, the `Runnable` used with the `Thread` (via new `Thread(Runnable)`) simply waits for tasks to be put into a `BlockingQueue`. When a new task is added to the `BlockingQueue` the `Thread` takes it and executes `run()`. This is how a single `Thread` can run more than one task without being destroyed and another one taking its place.

Note this means if all the pool's threads (or, in this case, single thread) are busy with a task any queued tasks will have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);` 
this will create only 5 threads in the `Executor`.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
        executorService.execute(worker); // How many threads are created?
    }
```

This creates 10 tasks that are submitted to the executor service for execution. 
And the ExecutorService will use the fixed 5 threads to execute those 10 tasks.
So Yes, you will have one thread doing multiple tasks without being re-created.

Comment: I understand Thread as 

`code` Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable{@override run()}); `code`

 How th shifts from one Runnable r1 to r2, without destroying th and recreating it?

Comment: Basically the worker threads never stop in a executor service unless the executor is stopped. Basically they execute a task and then wait for the next one.

Comment: The `WorkerThread` object isn't an actual thread, it's just an object wrapping a function. It doesn't create an OS thread. The Executor takes care of passing the function to the actual OS thread so it can run it.